# sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError - concurency problem in Pyramid with waitress

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, jinja2, pyramid

I have a simple query loading records from view (PostgreSQL):

```
    rows = DBSession.query(MyView).all()
```

next, I'm processing rows, copying them to rows1:

```
    for row in rows:
        # some calculation...
        rows1.append( row )
```

and finally, returning result to jinja2 renderer:

```
    return {"rows": rows1}
```

When there are few concurrent requests, some of them fails during jinja rendering with this error:

```
    sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Instance <MyView at 0x7f1e20237790> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/bhk3)
```

I suspect that the problem is somehow related to concurrency: if I set waitress to one thread, everything works fine.

Is there any way to enforce loading of all data before passing to jinja ?

Comment: The link in the error message describes the issue and how to resolve it. What did you try out of the documentation's three listed options?